# How to get an .htaccess rewrite rule with filtering directory and keeping parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'am trying to write a rewrite rule and I would like to change this:

```
http://domain.de/adServer/js/first/sec/ADTECH?loc=300&alias=Home&misc=1429871690242
```

to:

```
http://domain.de/adServer/js/ADTECH.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

where $_Get in ADTECH.php shout be:

`$_GET['a']=first |  $_GET['b']=sec  | $_GET['loc']=300  | $_GET['alias']=Home`

The .htaccess-file will be placed in root/adServer/js.
I tryed this without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /adServer/js/(.*)/(.*)/ADTECH$ 
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ADTECH$ /adServer/js/test.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

(My code brings the `$_GET['a']=first | $_GET['b']=sec` as new parameters but whats to do with the given parameters?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in `/adServer/js/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase /adServer/js/ 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ADTECH/?$ test.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Changes are:

1. Add required flags in `RewriteRule`. Esp important is `QSA` to preserve original query string.
2. Add appropriate `RewriteBase`.
3. Remove redundant `RewriteCond`
4. Use relative path for rewriting in `RewriteRule`.